# Reflection + LINQ

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm truing to use reflection with LINQ on a sub that set datasource of all my ComboBox:

Usual Method:

```
' ACAmp Panel
cboACPanelAmp.ValueMember = "IDACAmp"
cboACPanelAmp.DisplayMember = "Description"
cboACPanelAmp.DataSource = m_Entities.ACAmps.OrderBy(Function(c As ACAmp) c.SortOrder).ToList
```

Want to use that sub

```
FillCbo(cboACPanelAmp, "ACAmp")

Private Sub FillCbo(ByVal cbo As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinEditors.UltraComboEditor, ByVal entityName As String)

    cbo.ValueMember = "ID" & entityName
    cbo.DisplayMember = "Description"

    ' need to complete this line
    cbo.DataSource = GetType(RFOPSEntities).
                     GetProperty(entityName & "s").GetGetMethod().Invoke(m_Entities, Nothing)
    ' with this code
    ' .OrderBy(Function(c As ACAmp) c.SortOrder).ToList

    ' like this line
    cbo.DataSource = m_Entities.ACAmps.OrderBy(Function(c As ACAmp) c.SortOrder).ToList

End Sub
```

I can't figure out the last part of the last line, the LINQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  cbo.DataSource = GetType(RFOPSEntities).
                     GetProperty(entityName & "s").GetGetMethod().Invoke(m_Entities, Nothing)
```

In that line you need to tell the environment that that is a type that you can use linq on.

So I think that it is a RFOPSEntities, so something like

```
cbo.DataSource = DirectCast(GetType(RFOPSEntities)
                    .GetProperty(entityName & "s")
                    .GetGetMethod()
                    .Invoke(m_Entities, Nothing), RFOPSEntities)
```

Then you should be able to use your Linq OrderBy on that

```
cbo.DataSource = DirectCast(GetType(RFOPSEntities)
                    .GetProperty(entityName & "s")
                    .GetGetMethod()
                    .Invoke(m_Entities, Nothing), RFOPSEntities)
                    .OrderBy(Function(c As ACAmp) c.SortOrder).ToList
```

Comment: cbo.DataSource = DirectCast(GetType(RFOPSEntities) _
                                .GetProperty(entityName & "s") _
                                .GetGetMethod() _
                                .Invoke(m_Entities, Nothing), ObjectSet(Of ACAmp)).OrderBy(Function(c As ACAmp) c.SortOrder).ToList()

Answer (score 0):

Thank you msarchet I modifiy a bit but it work.

```
cbo.DataSource = DirectCast(GetType(RFOPSEntities) _
                           .GetProperty(entityName & "s") _
                           .GetGetMethod() _
                           .Invoke(m_Entities, Nothing), ObjectSet(Of ACAmp)))
                           .OrderBy(Function(c As ACAmp)) c.SortOrder).ToList()
```

Now I need to do semeting like that:

```
cbo.DataSource = DirectCast(GetType(RFOPSEntities) _
                                .GetProperty(entityName & "s") _
                                .GetGetMethod() _
                                .Invoke(m_Entities, Nothing), ObjectSet(Of Type.GetType("ACAmp"))).OrderBy(Function(c As Type.GetType("ACAmp")) c.SortOrder).ToList()
```

The Type.GetType("ACAmp") is not goog but the type could be pass by string. How ?